# Mongodb aggregation query for message unread count group by group_id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my problem : in my MongoDB database, I have a collection with Messages like :

```
{
  'id': 1,
  'message': 'Message 1',
  'groups': [1],
  'readBy': ['cust1','cust2'],
  'status': '1'
}
{
  'id': 2,
  'message': 'Message 2',
  'groups': [1],
  'readBy': ['cust2'],
  'status': '1'
}
{
  'id': 3,
  'message': 'Message 3',
  'groups': [2],
  'readBy': ['cust2','cust1'],
  'status': '1'
}
{
  'id': 4,
  'message': 'Message 4',
  'groups': [2],
  'readBy': ['cust2'],
  'status': '1'
}
{
  'id': 5,
  'message': 'Message 5',
  'groups': [2],
  'readBy': ['cust2'],
  'status': '1'
}
```

I have another collection for customer, in that I have maintained groups ids.
`'cust1'` is part of group id = `[1,2]`.
I want total group count from which messages is not read by `cust1`.
In above case count should be `2`.

I have tried by using below query, But it returns total unread message count.

```
db.Messages.aggregate(
   {$unwind : "$groups" },
   {$match:{ 
     "groups": {
            "$in": ["1","2"]
        }, 
        "status": "1",
        "readBy": {
            "$ne": "cust1"
        }
   }},
   {$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:1}}}
).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Query satisfy above functionality.

```
db.Messages.aggregate(
   {$unwind : "$groups" },
   {$match:{ 
     "groups": {
            "$in": ["1","2"]
        }, 
        "status": "1",
        "readBy": {
            "$ne": "cust1"
        }
   }},
   {$group:{_id:"$groups"}},
   {$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:1}}}
)
```